# Convert List to Array without java.util

Tags: java, arrays, list, casting

I would like to convert a `LinkedList` to an `Array` and I am not allowed to use
`java.util.*`. I've googled for about an hour and couldn't find anything.

It would be great if somebody could help me.

Comment: First off, how big does the array need to be? Then, how would you copy each element in turn to the array?

Comment: About 6 elements. Just int numbers. (1-9)

Comment: This sounds like a school assignment it - so here is a general way to do it:

 - Create a new array of the type you need of length `myLinkedList.size()`
 - Use a `for` loop to iterate the array
 - Assign to the array elements using `.get(i)`

Comment: Well, you want to use `LinkedList`, but you're not allowed to use it, because it is in `java.util.*`? Strange assignment. And btw: what have you tried so far?

Comment: You'd better tell us more about your `LinkedList`, since it's clearly not the built-in one if you're banned from `java.util`.

Comment: isn't the class `LinkedList` already in java.util..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    String[] arr = new String[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        arr[i] = list.get(i);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // print [a, b]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LinkedList's method toArray().
It looks somthing like this:

```
LinkedList<String> l = new LinkedList<>();
l.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Hope this helps.